# The word "chemist" and its origins?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I know *chemist* means someone who sells medicines or drugs. However, we use *physicist* for someone who studies/researches physics, and so will anyone naturally understand.

But it has always confused me why don't we use *chemist* similarly, and selling medicines is not completely related to studying chemistry. So what is the word's origins and why did its meaning came to be so unnatural?

Comment: Just because medicine is unrelated to chemistry today, [doesn't mean that was the case](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chemist&allowed_in_frame=0) when the word was actually coined. And wait a minute, how do you mean medicine is unrelated to chemistry today? It very much is, and always will be.

Comment: The word [chemist](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+chemist) is also used in a parallel meaning to _physicist_

Comment: @RegDwigнt Of course it is, but if you say only medicines is chemistry, it would be wrong. That is what I meant.

Comment: @Sawarnik I thought the term was used for a scientist that works in the field of chemistry/physics. I would call someone that sells medicines and drugs a pharmacist or a druggist, and would refer to a person that prepares medications as a pharmacist exclusively.

Comment: @ Nourished Gourmet The term "chemist's" (and certainly not the US "drugstore") is by far the most common way of referring to a pharmacist's in the UK.

Comment: @Nourished Gourmet, the word has that meaning as you can see in this link http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/chemist_1?q=chemist It also has the meaning that Sawarnik wrote http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/chemist_2 *Chemist* is the normal word in England and the rest of the UK, where *pharmacist* is less common and *druggist* is unknown and not in use.

Comment: @Tristanr Is "chemist" for "pharmacist" chiefly BrE? Or can its usage be found in some US dialects also?

Comment: @Nourished Gourmet, you can see in the second dictionary link that it's a British definition. I don't know if it's used at all, in the US, where *pharmacist* seems to be the normal word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**chemist (n.)** 
1560s, chymist, "alchemist," from Middle French chimiste, from Medieval Latin chimista, reduced from alchimista (see alchemy). Modern spelling is from c.1790. Meaning **"chemical scientist" is from 1620s; meaning "dealer in medicinal drugs"** (mostly in British English) is from 1745.

**Alchemist(n.)**
1510s, from Middle French alquemiste, from Medieval Latin alchimista (see alchemy). Earlier forms were alchemister (late 14c.), alkanamyer (late 15c.).

Etymonline.com

Actually they used to produce medicines themselves, and some of them still do it today  for simple prescriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Chemistry comes from alchemy, which comes from Arabic "al Khem". Khem is the name of the civilization once found in what is now called Egypt.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. However I don't think your answer is particularly relevant to the question which  is based on a misunderstanding.