# What is the etymology of 'Chemistry'?

Tags: etymology

Most studies of science end with the suffixes *-logy*, *-nomy* and *-metry*, as defined in the answer to the question [Meaning of '-onomy', '-ology' and '-ography'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116456/meaning-of-onomy-ology-and-ography/116457#116457), including examples like 'geology', 'astronomy' and 'photometry' (which I specialise in).

However, there are exceptions, in particular, the science of **chemistry**.  There is another discussion about the term, *chemist*, in the question [The word “chemist” and its origins?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165863/the-word-chemist-and-its-origins), and further from [OED](https://archive.org/stream/oed02arch#page/320/mode/2up):

> Of English formation: in 17th c. *chymistrie*, f. *chymist* (chemist) + -ry, ‘the art or practice of the chemist’; at first probably contemptuous, cf. *palmistry, sophistry, casuistry*, etc.

This question is about the actual term for the science itself – chemistry – what is its origin?  Additionally, does the fact the word ends in *-istry* and not one of the more standard suffixes have a connection to terms such as *palmistry* (as in the quote above)?

Answer (score 5):

The  term *chemistry* used to indicate an art rather than a science. That is probably why in the formation of the term the suffix **- ry**, meaning  '**art of** ' was chosen:

[Chemistry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Istry&searchmode=none):

> - c.1600, "alchemy," **from chemist + -ry**; also see chemical (adj.). The meaning "natural physical process" is 1640s, and the scientific study not so called until 1788. The figurative sense of "instinctual attraction or affinity" is attested slightly earlier, from the alchemical sense.

[-ry, -ery](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ery&allowed_in_frame=0): (Etymology)

> - word-forming element making nouns meaning "place for, **art of, condition of, quantity of,**" from Middle English -erie, from Latin -arius (see -ary).

[Etymology](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemistry):

> - The word chemistry comes from the word alchemy, an earlier set of practices that encompassed elements of chemistry, metallurgy, philosophy, astrology, astronomy, mysticism and medicine; it is commonly thought of as the quest to turn lead or another common starting material into gold.
> - In retrospect, the definition of chemistry has changed over time, as new discoveries and theories add to the functionality of the science. **The term "chymistry", in the view of noted scientist Robert Boyle in 1661, meant the subject of the material principles of mixed bodies.In 1663, "chymistry" meant a scientific art**, by which one learns to dissolve bodies, and draw from them the different substances on their composition.
> - The 1730 definition of the word "chemistry", as used by Georg Ernst Stahl, **meant the art of resolving mixed, compound, or aggregate bodies into their principles**; and of composing such bodies from those principles

(from Wikipedia)

Answer (score 3):

You should have looked  at *alchemy*, which is clearly the root of *chemistry*, both as a word and as an art - I mean science.

On alchemy (the *Al-* being clearly an Arabic article as in *alcohol* and *algebra*) the OED says

> Hellenistic Greek χημία , χημεία occurs c300 in a decree of the Roman Emperor Diocletian against ‘the old writings of the Egyptians, which treat of the χημία (transmutation) of gold and silver’. Hence, many scholars have postulated a supposed original sense ‘Egyptian art’ for this word, and identified it with Hellenistic Greek Χημία (Plutarch), a name for Egypt.

It goes on to discuss the similar Greek word for 'pouring' and theorize that it became by synecdoche the term for measuring and hence alchemy; but since it is clearly a homophone at best this smacks of desperation.

Comment: Well, if the latter theory turns out to be true, and [a similar one within Germanic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=god&searchmode=none) is also true … then we finally have firm evidence that science geeks have been telling the truth all these years: _chemistry **is** God_!

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that is sure to say about the etymology of chemistry is that there is a lot of uncertainty. See etymonline and en.wikipedia. Etymology can't explain everything. Some words have roots that are simply too old. Very often in earliest times word families intermingle and it is impossible to tell what family a word belongs to.